# How do I prove $\log_a abc + \log_b abc + \log_c abc = 1$

Tags: logarithms

Please how do I prove this

1/log_a abc +  1/log_b abc + 1/log_c abc = 1

Comment: You don't. This is plain wrong. A simple counterexample is $a=b=c=2$, and this is a very low-quality question, since you could have easily found this counterexample!!!

Comment: Wait. My mistake. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\log_x y = \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}$ and $\ln(xy)=\ln x + \ln y$. Applying those two properties will give you what you want.